# How to test Angular service with dependencies?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to unit test my service which has a dependency to another service.

my.service.ts:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  readonly initialObjects = [
    { title: 'Title1', url: '/title1' },
    { title: 'Title2', url: '/title2' },
    { title: 'Title3', url: '/title3' },
  ];

  objects$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private anotherService: AnotherService) {
    this.updateObjects();
  }

  updateObjects() {
    this.anotherService.getAllObjects().subscribe(objects => {
      if (objects.length === 0) {
        this.objects$.next(this.initialObjects);
      } else {
        const newObjects = [];
        objects.forEach(object => {
          newObjects.push({ title: object.name, url: `some-fancy-url/${object.id}` });
        });
        this.objects$.next([...this.initialObjects, ...objects]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

my.service.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AnotherService } from '../another.service';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let mockAnotherService;

  const mockObjects = [
    { id: '70c3d78c-90d9-44f6-aadc-ba2b993ba741', title: 'title1' },
    { id: 'fa08a156-edf6-4a42-bdae-99d91b5c6f32', title: 'title2' },
    { id: '551849d8-9b36-45d6-b6de-154f700abbcc', title: 'title3' },
  ];

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAnotherService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getAllObjects']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: AnotherService, useValue: mockAnotherService }
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('objects observable', () => {
    it('should contain only initial objects', () => {
      mockAnotherService.getAllObjects.and.returnValue(of([]));

      expect(service.objects$.value.length).toBe(3);
    });

    it('should contain all initial objects and all other available objects', () => {
      mockAnotherService.getAllObjects.and.returnValue(of(mockObjects));

      expect(service.objects$.value.length).toBe(6);

      for (let index = 3; index < service.objects$.value.length; index++) {
          expect(service.objects$.value[index].title).toEqual(mockObjects[index].title);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

another.service.ts (shortened)

```js
[...]

  private objects = [];

  getAllObjects() {
    return of(this.objects);
  }

[...]
```

The error message I get for all tests is:

> ...
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>      at Jasmine
>      at MyService.updateObjects (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.js:3667:55)
>   ...

I thought, that I created the spy with `jasmine.createSpyObj` which will be provided via the factory. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Your service calls its own this.updateObjects() method in the constructor. The constructor is invoked when you get the service, in beforeEach. At that time, you haven't told the mock other service to return anything yet.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after, and updated my comment.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. But how can I change the returnValue of the mockAnotherService then?

Comment: By executing `mockAnotherService.getAllObjects.and.returnValue(...);` **before** the first call to `TestBed.get(MyService)`. Or by avoiding calling the method from the constructor in the first place, and calling it in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are calling the service within constructor, any test case would be too late to mock the service. Instead, you can do following

```js
  const mockObjects = [
    { id: '70c3d78c-90d9-44f6-aadc-ba2b993ba741', title: 'title1' },
    { id: 'fa08a156-edf6-4a42-bdae-99d91b5c6f32', title: 'title2' },
    { id: '551849d8-9b36-45d6-b6de-154f700abbcc', title: 'title3' },
  ];

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { 
          provide: AnotherService, 
          useValue: { // you can create your fake service right here
            getAllObjects: () => of(mockObjects)
          }
        }
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Please see the comments under the question. This is only half of the answer and it wouldn’t solve all tests.

Comment: @HugoB. yeah I just saw that. Well the fastest solution would be to create two test suites and provide single test for each. Meanwhile, I'll try to think of another solution though.

Comment: For now I just moved the `service = TestBed.get(MyService)` after the `returnValue` method in the tests, like @JB Nizet said - and it’s working.